# Using Visual Studio native C++ unit testing framework with strings instead of wide strings

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, vs-unit-testing-framework

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio native C++ unit testing framework to work with **std::string** instead of **std::wstrings** ?

```
Assert::Equal<class T>(const T & t1,const T &t2)
```

requires the function

```
template<class T> std::wstring ToSring<class T>(const T & t) /* note the wstring here */
```

to be written/specialized by the test writer for the object to be tested (of type T). I already have this function:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & o, const T & t) /* note the ostream vs wostream */
```

I would like to re-use (build uppon a third party narrow strings library), but I don't have the wostream equivalent, and don't want to rewrite one.

What are my options ?

Comment: I use macros which convert messages as needed from `string` to `wstring` ... Then just use `Assert::Fail` instead of `Assert::AreEqual`

Comment: I would definitly go for it if there is no other solution, and I think it's worth an answer...

Answer (score 1):

If your class *did* have the `wostream` method then your specialization for `ToString` could simply use the provided macro `RETURN_WIDE_STRING`:

```
template<> static std::wstring ToString(const Foo &t) { RETURN_WIDE_STRING(t); }
```

But without changing the code under test, you could write a similar macro (or function) to convert the `ostream` to a `wstring` and use it in the same way:

```
template<> static std::wstring ToString(const Foo &t) { RETURN_WIDE_FROM_NARROW(t); }
```

The new macro might look something like:

```
#define RETURN_WIDE_FROM_NARROW(inputValue) \
        std::stringstream ss;\
        ss << inputValue;\
        auto str = ss.str();\
        std::wstringstream wss;\
        wss << std::wstring(str.begin(), str.end());\
        return wss.str();
```

You can also avoid the whole `ToString` specialization problem by using `Assert` variants that don't require it:

```
Assert::IsTrue(t1 == t2, L"Some descriptive fail message");
```

This is likely to be as much or more work though, depending how much detail you want in the fail messages.